# Nifi: Delete files from S3 when they are X days old

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have Nifi flow which is supposed to delete any files from S3 that are older than 7 days. I have used the following setup to get it done.

My `UpdateAttribute` processor has a `epoch_now` attribute that gets current epoch time.

On my `RouteOnAttribute` I have the following logic to filter out files that are younger than 7 days using this expression: `${epoch_now:minus(${s3.lastModified}):ge(604800000)}`

The problem is that `ListS3` processor will maintain state and it won't re-list all the files the next time to calculate if any files are expiring and need to be deleted. I looked around but I could not find something like `Get*` processor which would not maintain state. How do I fix this flow so that it run periodically and keeps deleting files that are 7 days old?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, NiFi does not currently have a processor to query S3 that way.

This might be a better fit for an [S3 Lifecycle Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html).  You can configure a rule for specific key prefixes, so S3 will automagically delete objects after 7 days.  From the S3 console:

- Select your bucket
- Select Properties
- Expand the Lifecycle section
- Click Add rule

There is a wizard-style interface to walk you through the configuration.

Comment: I actually ended up keeping a local copy of the files and used `GetFile` processor to always watch that local dir and if any file is more than 7 days old, delete them from local, route the `${filename}`  to `DeleteS3Object` and  delete from S3 as well.